# sql - replace argument not valid

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to replace the text of a column in a table

I tried out:

```
select replace([article], '<p>&nbsp;</p>', '') from Articles

update Articles
set article = replace(article, '<p>&nbsp;</p>', '')
where article like '<p>&nbsp;</p>'

or 

UPDATE [AJA].[dbo].[Articles]
   SET [article] = ' '
 WHERE [article] = '<p>&nbsp;</p>'
GO
```

and everytime it comes out with the error:

> argument 1 not valid in replace

What's wrong with it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the actual SQL Server error message? Can't see that in `SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE text LIKE '%argument%not valid in%'`

Comment: what is the datatype of `article`?

Comment: And those statements all do different things - the first should show you the correct data, but won't update it in the database; the second updates the article column removing the string you specify only on rows where article equals exactly `<p>&nbsp;</p>` (you're missing the wildcard characters on your like statement); the third one sets the article body equal to a space where article matches `<p>&nbsp;</p>` exactly.

Comment: is it safe to assume that article is of datatype text ?

Comment: If it is `text` datatype the full error message should tell you the problem at least on 2008 `Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.`

Comment: Hi, the column article is of type text, the full error message is: the type of data of the argument 1 of the function replace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've check out your problem verifying with two datatype i.e.

1. `ntext` : while working with ntext , it throws above error....Check out [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b709e/1)
2. `varchar(max)`: While working with varchar(max), it is perfectly workin....Check out [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56bab/1)

So, use `varchar(max)` datatype while working with html tag....

If you want to work on your previous type, then cast the column type as `varchar`

```
   SELECT REPLACE(CAST([article] as VARCHAR(MAX)), '<p>&nbsp;</p>', '')
   FROM Articles
```

Comment: Good to know :), but I cannot change the design of the table, thanks

Comment: Go with updated answer....Cast the column type into varchar while using query....

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because you've text datatype. With varchar datatype 
your query works fine.

You need to cast your field from `text to varchar` in order to use replace function.

```
Declare @mytable table
(
Article text
);

INSERT into @mytable VALUES('<p>&nbsp;</p>');
INSERT into @mytable VALUES('<p>&nbsp;</p>');
INSERT into @mytable VALUES('<p>&nbsp;</p>');
INSERT into @mytable VALUES('<b>&nbsp;</b>');


select replace(cast([article] as VARCHAR(8000)),'<p>&nbsp;</p>','')
from   @mytable
where Article LIKE '<p>&nbsp;</p>'
```

Comment: of course, this solution will cut off text longer than 8000 chars

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
UPDATE Articles SET article = REPLACE(article, '<p>&nbsp;</p>', '')
```

Work on the other replaces likewise . .

Comment: This will update all rows even those where the text doesn't exist. Read @Bridge's comment

Comment: Hi coosal, doesn' t work on me, same error invalid argument 1